# Make search string bold, but only from start of word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to implement a search where I only match and bold the start of the word in Javascript.

So, if you search for "choc", "chocolate" would appear, but if you search for "late", Chocolate wouldn't appear.

I've got:

```
if( queryString.match(new RegExp('/\b'+inputField.val()+'/', 'gi')) )
```

And then to highlight the word:

```
var tempName = queryString.replace(new RegExp('(^|\b)(' + inputField.val() + ')(|$)','ig'), '$1<strong>$2</strong>$3');
```

But nothing is working the way I had hoped.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Can your `inputField.val()` contain (or rather start/end with) a non-word character (i.e. `:`, or even `Я`)?

Comment: If so, you will have to [escape it first](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6969486/3894981).

Comment: @julmot: No, if the value can start with non-word char, `\b` won't work, and `(^|\s)` will only match before a whitespace or at the start of the string. Escaping is a must anyway, yes.

Answer (score 1):

**Example match**:

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pO9gQ0/1) or [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/uN5dX0/1)

RegExp:

```
/(^|\s)(late)/gmi
```

or

```
/\b(late)/gmi
```

This will match:

Chocolate **late**choco

**Example replacement**:

```js
var search = "Chocolate latechoco";
document.write(search.replace(/\b(late)/gmi, "<strong>$1</strong>"));
```

Also note that your search string `inputField.val()` should always be escaped. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex/6969486#6969486) to learn how.